# List of domain object properties, excluding associations

Tags: grails, groovy, properties, associations, grails-orm

What is the best way of getting a map of all properties of a domain object, excluding the associations? In particular I need to exclude the `hasMany` associations (collections.)

Right now I'm hardwiring the list of properties to exclude:

```
def p = someBook.properties
p = p.subMap(p.keySet() - ['authors', 'editors', 'formats'])
```

I did make sure that `properties` returns a lazy collection, insofar as subMap() and keySet() are concerned, so that the excluded properties are not actually fetched from the DB.

But I'd rather not hardcode the list of associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude all associations by discarding the key value pairs from `properties`.

```
someBook.properties.findAll { !( it.key in someBook.hasMany?.keySet() ) }
```

Comment: `someBook.hasMany` ! that's brilliant!! And quite obvious, now that you mention it. thank you

Comment: I will merge your suggestion with my `subMap`, because `findAll` executes the DB queries for the excluded properties too